# When opening a VS2013 solution in VS2015, will I be prompted/required to convert to the newer version?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

We're investigating upgrading from VS2013 to VS2015 for C# and C++ solutions. Will opening a VS2013 solution in VS2015 require/suggest converting the project and/or solution files to the newer version, or will they just load with no mention that they are from an earlier version?

Comment: @HansPassant I reworded my title so your answer might require revision.

Comment: Since there's a "OR" in the question, the answer is definitely "yes" :-)

Comment: @HansPassant Why is the second "No" longer then the first one? Is it a "Nooo"? :)

Answer (score 1):

No. Starting at Visual Studio 2010 SP1, no solution conversion is required to open an old solution with a newer version of the IDE (and the other way around), and if all your projects are C# and C++, you'll be able to work with VS2015 just fine. Note however that additional data may be added to the solution file, but this will not break backwards compatibility (your soultion will still open in VS2013).

More information: [Porting, Migrating, and Upgrading Visual Studio Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx)